# Unity странное разрешение камеры

Tags: unity3d, 2d, экран

Делаю игру, запускаю в Unity, размер камеры один, а когда запускаю exe-шник размер другой

Вот скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Unity 2018.4.17f1 Personal.

Как это пофиксить?

Comment: В Юнити вы смотрели в вкладке Scene. В game можно попробовать, как будет смотреться игра на разных экранах. Я предполагаю, что у вас там стоит не 1980 на 1080, как в готовой игре, а другое разширение, от чего и разные картинки

Comment: @МаксимБончев а можно ли как-то сделать чтобы везде была одинаковая картинка? Ну или хотя бы ничего не обрезалось

Comment: подгоните свою игру под более маленький экран, а для остального пространства, которое будет видно только при большем экране, просто сделайте обычный фон, или добавте чего-то. Можно сделать и лучше, но я так делал, и всё работало неплохо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема, что вы подогнали размер под большое разрешение. В итоге на меньшем разрешении игра срезана. Как вариант выхода из ситуации, подогнать всё под маленький экран, а вне сцены подабавлять другие элементы интерфейса. Таким образом на маленьком экране будет весь самый главный игровой процесс, а для большего экрана будет видно самое главное, и то, чем вы украсите остальное пространство. К примеру, так сделали в Clash Royal:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

При тестировании через эдитор выставите будущее разрешение с выпадающем списке. *сейчас у вас free aspect стоит
Плюс на будущее надо сделать адаптивный размер UI

Answer (score 0):

У вас имеется, допустим, Canvas. В нем у вас, допустим, обьект кнопка. Когда вы нажимаете на неё, у вас справа (в инспекторе) появляется квадратик, а в нём имеются красные линии. Вам надо, чтобы обьект прилегал к боку, либо был по середине. Итак, допустим, ставите налево и проверяете, вуаля ваш обьект теперь слева. Первая точка.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).